# How To Maintain cookies when browser closed?

Tags: cookies

I have created a cookie using HttpCookie class.I am able to read and write cookies but when i close my browser it's get expire.

Comment: Have you set the expiry date of the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be dealing with `session cookies`, you might be looking for permanent cookies.

From Mozilla Developer Docs:

> **Permanent Cookies:**
>   Instead of expiring when the client closes, permanent cookies expire at a specific date (Expires) or after a specific length of time (Max-Age).

Something like:

`Set-Cookie: id=a3fWa; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT;`

This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) might be useful.